# Run flowtype checker manually

Tags: intellij-idea, flowtype

I have the IDEA Ultimate 2018.1 with flowtype (flow-bin) configured and all the checkboxes selected. I followed this guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/flow-type-checker.html

The type checking needs much time to be executed. I change something in my code (reverting a wrong annotation, or creating a wrong one), and I need to wait around 30 seconds to get the correct annotation, this is, IDEA triggers the flow server to analyse the files and modify the editor accordingly. That is quite a lot.

Can I trigger that type checking analysis manually inside IDEA to get the editor updated? Or can I change the auto-running interval?

Comment: What version of flow are you using?

Comment: Exactly, that was my problem. My version was 0.26.0, now it is 0.74.0.

Comment: If your issue is resolved (which it sounds like it is), you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

As Kraus noticed, my version of flow-bin was old.

I was using the version 0.26.0 instead of the new 0.74.0, mainly because when I updated flow I was not using `flow-bin` but `flow`...

Thanks. Now IDEA and flow are fast.